# XML Schema- how to match any integer?

Tags: xml, xsd, integer, xml-validation

I need to write a XML file which should conform to a schema. The schema enforces datatype of the element (happens to be process id on Linux) to be an integer.

This fragment of the code passed the validation-

```
<pid datatype="int">123</pid>
```

However, I won't know "123" or the process id beforehand, as such, I want to write something like this-

```
 <pid datatype="int">*</pid>
```

Obviously this doesn't work as * is seen as string as opposed to integer.

My question is - is there a way I can enter a value **in XML file** which will pass the test?

EDIT- here is the schema- 
http://oval.mitre.org/language/version5.10/ovaldefinition/documentation/unix-definitions-schema.html#process58_object

Comment: Share your schema...if the schema is authored to expect numeric datatype then there is no way to bypass that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through the schema definition, **pid** can either be empty or can contain a numeric value. So there if there is no data to be passed in then just specify it as `<pid datatype="int"></pid>` or `<pid />`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow either an integer or an asterisk, change the schema to use a type like this:

```
<xs:element name="pid">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union>
      <xs:simpleType ref="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="*"/>
        </
      </
    </
  </
</
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could also define a simple type in your XSD with a **regex**, as follows :

```
<!-- definition of simple types -->
<simpleType name="pidType">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>A number or *</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="\d+|\*{1}" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Then you can use it :

```
<element name="pid" type="tns:pidType"></element>
```